# How to create a new table from an existing table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
dbo.Profile_Updated
  (
     BusinessName VARCHAR,
     ContactName  VARCHAR,
     Address      VARCHAR,
     City         VARCHAR,
     State        VARCHAR,
     Postalcode   INT PRIMARY KEY,
     Phonenumber  VARCHAR
  )
```

This is my current table but now I want to create new table from the existing `Profile_Updated` table column, I mean the new table (`PostalDB`) needs to contain the columns `City, State, Postalcode` based on `Profile_Updated` table.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you just mean `SELECT INTO`:

```
SELECT City, State, Postalcode
  INTO dbo.PostalDB
  FROM dbo.Profile_Updated;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX p ON dbo.PostalDB(PostalCode);
CREATE INDEX ... -- you'll need to fill in these details
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing things in the wrong order.  You should have the PostalDB table created and populated first with a name like PostalDBId as the primary key.  The PostalDBId should be effectively meaningless.  It should not be a zip code or anything like that.

Then, your Profile_Updated needs a different primary key, something that's not related to the PostalDB table.  You also want another field that is a foreign key to the PostalDb table.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT City, State, Postalcode
INTO dbo.PostalDB
FROM dbo.Profile_Updated
```

The `INTO` clause will create a new table using the attributes from the source. The A little web searching will reveal many other possible solutions.