# How can I save one table column values to another table values?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

[image]

I have 2 tables 
Table 1 = Profile_Update
Table 2 = PostalDB

Here Table 1 column(BusinessName, ContactName, City, State, Postalcode{PrimaryKey}, etc..) values wants to store Table 2(City, State, Postalcode{PrimaryKey}) column also. How can I save one table column values to another table values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000854/how-to-create-a-new-table-from-an-existing-table is not the same question?

Comment: Having a primary key on postal code is probably not wise

Comment: Question is still unclear. The wording sounds like the second table doesn't exist, but in Object Explorer it's clear that it does. Is the `PostalDB` table empty (meaning you need an insert), or does the `PostalDB` table populated (meaning you need an update and possibly also an insert)?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring that having a primary key on postal code is not smart (since in some cases multiple cities can share a postal code, and surely you don't want to allow only one user from any postal code), maybe what you are looking for is this:

```
UPDATE p SET city = pu.city, state = pu.state
  FROM dbo.PostalDB AS p
  INNER JOIN dbo.Profile_Update AS pu
  ON p.Postalcode = pu.Postalcode;

INSERT dbo.PostalDB(city, state, Postalcode)
  SELECT city, state, postalcode
  FROM dbo.Profile_Update AS pu
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.PostalDB
      WHERE Postalcode = pu.Postalcode
  );
```

Comment: Gentle man sorry to say that the data will not saved automatically to PostalDb table, but profile_update table saved data perfectly, if i execute the query means then only it will added in the PostalDb table..my need is to saved data automatically to PostalDb also based on the Entry of Profile_Update Table as per your suggestion i remove the Postalcode as primary key..Kindly Help..

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what the problem is. You want to store postalcode, city and state twice, in a second table, automatically? Why? Just create a view if you need to be able to access the same data, redundantly, using two different table names. You can do what you want using a trigger but I think it is a complete waste of time, effort and storage.

Comment: yes if enter the postal code(primary key) just retrieve the data field of city, state and so on, so no need to enter manually so for i maintain the second table to retrieve data purpose..

Comment: Why can't you retrieve data from the first table? Your questions make little sense unless you can explain WHY.

Comment: yes i try..even though i will populate the DB based on the Pincode so for anyway thanks for ur great idea.. i will workout now..if i have a question i buzz u..thanks gentle man..

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT ... INTO
```

when you are creating a new table.

Otherwise

```
Insert INTO table (columns...)   (SELECT ... FROM ... where ...)
```